# How to export the content of an Android Studio .trace file to a text file

Tags: android, android-profiler

I have done several performance tests with Android Studio Profiler. I exported the files but i want to export the information that is represented graphically to a text file (% of cpu usage, timestamps, etc).

I have tried to use dmtracedump but I get the following error: ERROR: not at start of version (found 'SLOW�'). My environment is Ubunto 16.04.

What tools and how can i do this?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

This will depend on what type of trace your are exporting.

As of Android studio 4.0 System Trace captures are exported as atrace trace data that can be converted to html using systrace from the SDK.

Simpleperf captures are exported as a post processed (symbolized capture).

Art captures (java samples/instrumented) are exported in the format we capture them from the jvm.  You can use dmtracedump on those captures.